# Installing reflex-dom likely to break ghcjs

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghcjs, reflex, ghcjs-dom

I am trying to install `reflex` and `reflex-dom` using `cabal install` I got the following error messages:

```
$ cabal install reflex-dom

...

cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
lens-4.15.1
ghcjs-0.2.0
free-4.12.4
kan-extensions-5.0.1
adjunctions-4.3
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
```

`ghcjs` on GitHub is at [0.2.0](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs/tree/master) on the "master" branch and [0.2.1](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs/tree/dedupe) on a branch called "dedupe".  And I am also scared of breaking `lens`.  **Is there any way to install** `reflex` **and** `reflex-dom` **in a consistant way?**  Maybe I need to change the `.cabal` file

---

#### Here is the full response from terminal

```
$ cabal install reflex-dom

Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
bifunctors-5.3 (latest: 5.4.1) (via: reflex-dom-0.3 these-0.6.2.1 lens-4.13.2.1 free-4.12.4 semigroupoids-5.0.1 profunctors-5.2) (new version)
data-default-instances-base-0.1.0.1 (via: data-default-0.5.3) (new package)
data-default-0.5.3 (latest: 0.7.1.1) (via: reflex-dom-0.3) (new version)
dependent-sum-0.3.2.2 (latest: 0.4) (via: reflex-dom-0.3 reflex-0.4.0 dependent-sum-template-0.0.0.5 dependent-map-0.2.4.0) (new package)
dependent-map-0.2.4.0 (via: reflex-dom-0.3 reflex-0.4.0) (new package)
exception-transformers-0.4.0.5 (via: reflex-dom-0.3 reflex-0.4.0) (new package)
haskell-src-exts-1.17.1 (latest: 1.19.1) (via: reflex-0.4.0 haskell-src-meta-0.6.0.14) (new version)
haskell-src-meta-0.6.0.14 (latest: 0.7.0.1) (via: reflex-0.4.0) (new version)
profunctors-5.2 (via: these-0.6.2.1 lens-4.13.2.1 adjunctions-4.3 free-4.12.4) (reinstall) (changes: bifunctors-5.4.1 -> 5.3)
raw-strings-qq-1.1 (via: reflex-dom-0.3) (new package)
ref-tf-0.4.0.1 (via: reflex-dom-0.3 reflex-0.4.0) (new package)
semigroupoids-5.0.1 (latest: 5.1) (via: these-0.6.2.1 lens-4.13.2.1 kan-extensions-5.0.1 adjunctions-4.3 free-4.12.4) (new version)
free-4.12.4 (via: lens-4.13.2.1 kan-extensions-5.0.1 adjunctions-4.3) (reinstall) (changes: bifunctors-5.4.1 -> 5.3, semigroupoids-5.1 -> 5.0.1)
adjunctions-4.3 (via: kan-extensions-5.0.1) (reinstall) (changes: semigroupoids-5.1 -> 5.0.1)
kan-extensions-5.0.1 (via: lens-4.13.2.1) (reinstall) (changes: semigroupoids-5.1 -> 5.0.1)
lens-4.13.2.1 (latest: 4.15.1) (via: reflex-dom-0.3) (new version)
th-extras-0.0.0.4 (via: dependent-sum-template-0.0.0.5) (new package)
dependent-sum-template-0.0.0.5 (via: reflex-dom-0.3) (new package)
these-0.6.2.1 (latest: 0.7.3) (via: reflex-dom-0.3 reflex-0.4.0) (new package)
reflex-0.4.0 (via: reflex-dom-0.3) (new package)
utf8-string-1.0.1.1 (via: glib-0.13.4.1 cairo-0.13.3.1) (new package)
cairo-0.13.3.1 (via: webkitgtk3-0.14.2.1 gtk3-0.14.6 pango-0.13.3.1) (new package)
glib-0.13.4.1 (via: reflex-dom-0.3 webkitgtk3-javascriptcore-0.13.2.0 ghcjs-dom-0.2.4.0 webkitgtk3-0.14.2.1 gtk3-0.14.6 pango-0.13.3.1 gio-0.13.3.1) (new package)
gio-0.13.3.1 (via: gtk3-0.14.6) (new package)
pango-0.13.3.1 (via: webkitgtk3-0.14.2.1 gtk3-0.14.6) (new package)
gtk3-0.14.6 (via: reflex-dom-0.3 webkitgtk3-javascriptcore-0.13.2.0 ghcjs-dom-0.2.4.0 webkitgtk3-0.14.2.1) (new package)
webkitgtk3-0.14.2.1 (via: reflex-dom-0.3 webkitgtk3-javascriptcore-0.13.2.0 ghcjs-dom-0.2.4.0) (new package)
ghcjs-dom-0.2.4.0 (latest: 0.7.0.4) (via: reflex-dom-0.3) (new package)
webkitgtk3-javascriptcore-0.13.2.0 (latest: 0.14.2.1) (via: reflex-dom-0.3) (new package)
reflex-dom-0.3 (new package)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
lens-4.15.1
ghcjs-0.2.0
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
```

and similar for installing reflex

```
$ cabal install reflex

Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
bifunctors-5.3 (latest: 5.4.1) (via: these-0.6.2.1 semigroupoids-5.0.1 profunctors-5.2) (new version)
dependent-sum-0.3.2.2 (latest: 0.4) (via: reflex-0.4.0 dependent-map-0.2.4.0) (new package)
dependent-map-0.2.4.0 (via: reflex-0.4.0) (new package)
exception-transformers-0.4.0.5 (via: reflex-0.4.0) (new package)
haskell-src-exts-1.17.1 (latest: 1.19.1) (via: reflex-0.4.0 haskell-src-meta-0.6.0.14) (new version)
haskell-src-meta-0.6.0.14 (latest: 0.7.0.1) (via: reflex-0.4.0) (new version)
profunctors-5.2 (via: these-0.6.2.1) (reinstall) (changes: bifunctors-5.4.1 -> 5.3)
ref-tf-0.4.0.1 (via: reflex-0.4.0) (new package)
semigroupoids-5.0.1 (latest: 5.1) (via: these-0.6.2.1) (new version)
these-0.6.2.1 (latest: 0.7.3) (via: reflex-0.4.0) (new package)
reflex-0.4.0 (new package)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
lens-4.15.1
ghcjs-0.2.0
free-4.12.4
kan-extensions-5.0.1
adjunctions-4.3
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
```

Comment: Most people use stack to avoid this kind of error. I haven't had major version issues since I started using stack. Maybe an option for you?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: @DaveCompton this is Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way that I know of to install reflex and reflex-dom (and ghcjs too) in a consistent way on a linux environment is to follow the [setup instructions on the reflex-platform readme](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-platform) .

The process amounts to cloning the reflex-platform repository and running a script, "try-reflex" from inside that repository.  The try-reflex script starts a shell from which you can run ghcjs will full access to reflex/reflex-dom .  This shell environment is independent of what you previously installed on your computer so you don't have to worry about messing up lenses or any other cabal package you already have in place.

Comment: The 'reflex-platform/try-reflex' script has become my default haskell work environment, not only for ghcjs but also for ghc.  It's both simple and reliable.