# how to construct a Map Text Text object?

Tags: css, string, haskell

I am a newcomer to Haskell and I am trying to build a simple website with a library called Reflex.Dom and the Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) are represented as a `Map Text Text` object, that's nice but Haskell is distinguishing between three, nearly-identical objects:

- `String`
- `Text`
- `[Char]`

Certainly, in Python or JavaScript these are the same or nearly the same and functions can be used interchangeably between one object and the other.  Not the case in Haskell.

```
 "style" =: pack("color:red")
```

how about

```
 "style" =: pack("color:red; font-family: Helvetica;")
```

If I add another style element, I get an error message:

```
square-01.hs:6:47:
    Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: Text
    In the second argument of ‘(=:)’, namely ‘pack ("color:red")’
    In the second argument of ‘elAttr’, namely
      ‘("style" =: pack ("color:red"))’
```

Here is a little bit from Prelude but I don't really get it.

```
Prelude Reflex.Dom Data.Text Data.Map> "a" =: pack("b")
fromList [("a","b")]

Prelude Reflex.Dom Data.Text Data.Map> :t "a" =: pack("b")
"a" =: pack("b") :: Map [Char] Text

Prelude Reflex.Dom Data.Text Data.Map> "a" =: "b"
fromList [("a","b")]

Prelude Reflex.Dom Data.Text Data.Map> :t "a" =: "b"
"a" =: "b" :: Map [Char] [Char]

Prelude Reflex.Dom Data.Text Data.Map> :t (=:)
(=:) :: k -> a -> Map k a
```

Comment: Add `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` to the top of your file and watch these errors vanish.

Comment: More generally, `[Char]` and `String` are identical, but `Text` is different.

Comment: @Alec it's already there

Comment: Apologies. My first comment is misplaced. My second comment still holds. To construct a `Map Text Text`, you'll need to add a type annotation. `"a" =: "b" :: Map Text Text`. Basically, with `OverloadedStrings` enabled, all strings have the type `IsString a => a`. Unless otherwise constrained, GHC has some defaulting magic to pick `a ~ String`.

Comment: But apparently `elAttr` wants a `Map String String`, so you just need to get rid of the `pack`. (`pack` converts `String` to `Text`.)

Comment: @ReidBarton thank you very much

Comment: As @ReidBarton says, the hackage documentation for `elAttr` states that the second argument should be a `Map String String` .  However in the **latest** version of `reflex-dom`, that second argument has been changed to `Map Text Text`.  If you installed reflex using 'reflex-platform/try-reflex' per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42323953/509928) you should have the `Map Text Text` version.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at the repository https://github.com/hansroland/reflex-dom-inbits.

For an answer to your question see the examples *dom03.hs* and *dom04.hs* in the *src* directory.

The file *tutorial.md* contains a beginner friendly introduction to reflex-dom and explains the examples. The tutorial is still *work in progress*.